# python - split string with dynamic delimeter

Tags: python

I have

```
s = "[[[ab_1]]] bla1 [[[cd_3]]] bla2 "
```

I want to split `s` into `"bla1"` and `"bla2"`. the thing is, `ab_1` and `cd_3` are dynamic literals. they can be anything in form `"letters_numbers"`.

I am stuck like never before.. I tried with `split()` but it is getting ugly because `s` can be a long string with multiple delimeters in it..

any pythonic ideas?

Comment: regex ? import re ; re.search|match won't do it ?

Comment: Can you post what the exact answer would look like for the given string `s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split).

Something like the following regular expression might do it:

```
In [11]: re.split("\s*\[{3}.*?\]{3}\s*", s)
Out[11]: ['', 'bla1', 'bla2 ']

In [12]: re.split("\s*\[{3}.*?\]{3}\s*", s.strip())[1:]
Out[12]: ['bla1', 'bla2']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "[[[ab_1]]] bla1 [[[cd_3]]] bla2 "

import  re

print(re.findall("(?<=\s)\w+",s))
['bla1', 'bla2']
```

Or if you want to include punctuation:

```
s = "[[[ab_1]]] bla1 [[[cd_3]]] bla2!"

import re

print(re.findall(r"\s(\w+\S)",s)
['bla1', 'bla2!']
```

Comment: @ReutSharabani, because the OP onlys wants the two words.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

s = "[[[ab_1]]] bla1 [[[cd_3]]] bla2 "
print filter(bool, re.split('\W', s))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['ab_1', 'bla1', 'cd_3', 'bla2']
```

And if you want only the "bla"s:

```
s = "[[[ab_1]] bla1 [[[cd_3]]] bla2 "
print filter(lambda x: re.match('\w+|\s+', x), re.sub('\[.*?\]', ' ', s))
```

will output:

```
bla1   bla2
```

Comment: `not not x`? What is that about?

Comment: @khelwood just messing with you :) you can use `lambda x:x` and it'll work just fine

Comment: Functionally the same as just using `filter(bool, re.split('\W', s))` then. I just wondered why someone would think `not not x` was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string and use [`str.isalnum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) in a list comprehension :

```
>>> [i for i in s.split() if i.isalnum()]
['bla1', 'bla2']
```